# Is there a way to read the value of a Tag Manager variable in the client?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We are setting up some server-side Google Analytics events and we recently transitioned our GA implementation to use Google Tag Manager. I would like to maintain some of the constants we use in GTM so that they can be controlled from there. A good example is which GA Tracking ID to use. We currently store this in a lookup field called "GA - Tracking ID Lookup".

We would like to find a way to retrieve the value of this GTM variable in javascript code on our site. Is this possible?

Comment: GTM lookup variables are build over the input values (e.g. hostname or anything else) so you may just replicate the same logic in a JS. GTM doesn't expose explicitly it's internal values to client's side in a readable format

Comment: @ДмитроБулах, but that JS could still be part of a custom HTML tag in GTM, which would avoid having to store the values in two places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way for you to manage this is to use the [Data Layer](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide). Your JS will be able to read the values in the Data Layer and GTM will also be able to.

If you were to go this route, you'd change your lookup variable to a datalayer variable for GTM.

Examples:

Have your server write out a DOM element to contain the analytics tracking ID something like

```
<meta name="ga-tracking-id" content="UA-1234567890-1" />
```

You can also store the same information into the dataLayer:

```
<script>
   dataLayer = [{
      'ga-tracking-id': 'UA-1234567890-1',
   }];
</script>
```

This data can then be retrieved using the DataLayer variable type in GTM.

Another way you can manage this through one GTM container is to create a [lookup table](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7683362#lookup_table) in GTM, then depending on which hostname, use a different tracking ID.

Though I'm not sure how you're managing this, but it also could be easier to just use different containers all together instead of varying tracking ID in one container.

Comment: "use the data layer" in which way? I'm trying to determine the value of a constant in GTM.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I get it. Create a Data Layer Variable in GTM and populate it with this value. Then it will be readable from scripts on the page by reading them from the datalayer.